# Jenkins execute shell not able to find gradle commands

Tags: shell, jenkins, gradle

I am trying to trigger gradle command in execute shell of a  particular node from jenkins master and it's trowing an exception as-

```
gradle: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

However, gradle command works if am trying to execute shell in the same node itself under local workspace.

**What I understood-**

- Triggering any job from remote by default try to search executable like 'adb', 'gradle' in /usr/local/bin of node machine (Macintosh)
- read-write access should be there for '.gradle' folder

**What I have done-**

- added .gradle inside /usr/local/bin of slave
- granted read-write access to .gradle

Here, both node-jenkins and master-jenkins have gradle v2.5 installed. Why execute shell triggered from master jenkins not able to find gradle in slave jenkins, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try run `env` before your try to run gradle. and compare it to `env` from the command line. I think that Jenkins use another path.

Comment: gradle_home is not getting passed while triggering job in slave. However, the value for the same is set under bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue where `gradle` command working fine on machine where `jenkins` is installed but the same command was not working on slave.

Solution:

1. You need to set `GRADLE_HOME` on slave.
2. Most important: set `PATH` into the slave configuration [copy the exact PATH path from slave machine and copy it into Jenkins slave configuration under `Jenkins`--> `Manage Jenkins`--> `Manage Node`--> `NodeName`(your node name)--> `Configure and search for Node Properties`-->`Environment variables`]
3. save

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have added additional PATH env variable, then it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue

- verify you add Gradle Plugin to your jenkins
- **Verify that you inside the Folder where exist the "gradle.build" file**

*my example: the location of my gradle.build was insifr the foulder automation-api*
[image]